# how to parse xml files of text in a flip view in android app

Tags: android, xml-parsing, viewflipper

hi i am trying to parse an XML file. My XML file looks as below

```
<Chapters>
    <chapter>
       <Question>abc</Question>
       <answer>avksn</answer>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <Question>def</Question>
       <answer>avksn</answer>
        <image>a.png</image>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
         <Question>ccsv</Question>
        <answer>avksn</answer>
         <hint>acd</hint>
    </chapter>
</Chapters>
```

I know to parse the XML file normally, my problem is i want to show the Questions one by one, ie only one question must be viewed at a time and i have placed a flip view. When the flip button is clicked the related answer must be viewed in the next page.

In some cases the other tags such as  and  must be viewed along with question tag. how to do this..... pls help me friends.....

Comment: i have two xml files to be parsed. One is to viewed in list view and the other one is above said. i have done the first xml file....

Comment: Yes, that's clear... but where are you having problems? can you paste the code you are using? also, if your app crashes running your code, paste the logcat.

Comment: it shows the following error in logcat   03-30 10:38:24.761: ERROR/(793): org.xml.sax.SAXException: No input specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you store your xml file? I think it's better to use XmlPullParser, e.g.:

```
XmlPullParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.data_file);
int eventType = parser.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                String tagName = parser.getName();
                ...
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
}
```

If you store xml in assets - use AssetsManager to obtain XmlPullParser for it.